# Creating a row of three boxes separated

Tags: css

I am new to css and I have a menu bar that I am working on however I am having a problem with one of the menu ("LINKS") items. If you roll over the Links menu item your notice I have three boxes there that I am trying to separate into there own area. Right now they are over lapping each other. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have tried margin-left and padding-left and I find that they either move the box further to the right or widen the box more. But they don't space them out.

You can find the menu bar here: http://jsfiddle.net/vtjPR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three boxes (div.col_1) have a set width of 125px. However, within the boxes are the link lists (ul.blackbox) with a defined width of 150px. Also, its list items have a defined width of 130px.

Comment: Well, this means that your inner element (ul) is wider than your outer element (div = box). This will most likely cause the overlapping. Either make the boxes wider or make the lists less wide.

Comment: Thank you I was able to get it worked out thanks to your suggestion!